# Help with understanding Einstein's thought experiment of the train

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers, aether

My understanding is that Einstein claimed that the aether model of light is inconsistent with the principle of relativity (that you cannot tell the difference between constant velocity and being stationary). This is shown through the thought experiment where a train is moving at the speed of light and an observer inside it is looking at a mirror. Since the light emitted by him will travel towards the mirror at the speed of light relative to the aether and the train is moving at the speed of light relative to the aether, the light will never reach the mirror, meaning he will not observe himself. This breaks the principle of relativity as it tells him he is moving at the speed of light.

My question is why can't this be explained by just saying that if you wanted to stop the observer from knowing whether they are moving relative to the aether you had to stop interaction with the aether?

For example, if we had allowed interaction with air from outside the train we could easily tell we were moving relative to the outside air, yet no one would say we are breaking the principle of relativity, rather you would say that in order for it to apply we must stop the observer from being able to interact with the outside air. Why don't we say something similar about an aether model?

(Note: I am not saying that the aether is correct, just that it doesn't seem that this proves it inconsistent with the principle of relativity.) If anyone could explain where my misunderstanding is or why this doesn't work that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "whether they are moving relative to the aether you had to stop interaction with the aether?" and what would *that* interaction be?

Comment: The aether was already inconsistent with relativity in Galileo's time.  Galileo didn't use a train to make that argument (because trains weren't invented, yet). He used a ship. In essence, Einstein didn't have to make any such arguments. They were well known at the time because they had been made centuries earlier, already. The only scientifically relevant question was how one could unify electrodynamics with classical mechanics. Einstein showed that classical mechanics was merely a low velocity approximation of the correct theory. That's pretty much it.

Comment: Here's an actual link to Galileo's ship https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_ship#The_proposal.  This is _400 year old_ science, people.

Comment: Can somebody tell me why this question was downvoted? I remember that as a student I and my classmates were asking similar questions. I do not believe that the downvoters here were born with the full intuitive insight never to have wondered and be bothered by these questions.

Comment: @hyportnex can't speak for everyone, but probably mostly because of the forlorn clinging to the concept of an "aether".  At this point only cranks and Einstein haters still think it is worth bringing up.  The downvoters may well value actual learning over "intuitive insight".

Comment: @m4r35n357 *The downvoters may well value actual learning over "intuitive insight"*, you have misunderstood the intent I wrote. It is very difficult to learn anything new if it is contrary to very deeply intuition, and giving such a deeply held conviction as simultaneity is a hindrance to learning. One must be allowed to start questioning somewhere and I believe few of us are born with the the insight that the velocity of light is the same in all inertial frames; I sure did not have that.

Comment: @hyportnex not sure about that.  I strongly suspect most people who want to know about SR _have_ been told that it is "weird and unintuitive", that is part of the appeal right?

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is that Einstein claimed that the æther model of light is inconsistent with the principle of relativity (that you cannot tell the difference between constant velocity and being stationary).

One of the smart things that Einstein did was to mostly stay out of the debate. Instead, the presentation of the Special Theory of Relativity simply does not mention the æther, because it is irrelevant. Of course, during those days it would have been a hot topic, and people would talk about all the crazy properties that the æther would have to have, in order to explain the known physical results at the time. For example, it would have to be incredibly tense to have such a high speed of light, yet it would have to be incredibly loose, so that when things other than light passes through it, there would be almost no retardation.

> This is shown through the thought experiment where a train is moving at the speed of light and an observer inside it is looking at a mirror. Since the light emitted by him will travel towards the mirror at the speed of light relative to the æther and the train is moving at the speed of light relative to the æther, the light will never reach the mirror, meaning he will not observe himself. This breaks the principle of relativity as it tells him he is moving at the speed of light.

It turns out that the arguments involving precisely the speed of light are all wrong. No massive object may actually get to the speed of light, and all massless objects must move exactly at the speed of light. There is a discontinuity there and it is important to get this correct. If you read that Einstein made such an argument, which is more than likely, you should not pay so much attention on them.

> My question is why can't this be explained by just saying that if you wanted to stop the observer from knowing whether they are moving relative to the æther you had to stop interaction with the æther?

This is the most easiest to refute: How are you proposing that anybody begin to try to achieve this? With air, you can just seal the windows. How are you expecting that anybody can block out the æther?